# Numpy/pandas element-wise in operator

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have array (or rather pandas frame) that has a column `A`, values in this columns are integers (let's assume that they belong to range 1..10).

Now I would have to select rows in this array that have `A` values of `{3, 6, 9}` (in this example it is possible to just or `==` operations but in real life this set be a lot longer.

Is there any funciton in either library (`pandas` or `numpy`) that allows me to do following fast:

```
arr = pandas.DataFrame(...)
values = [3, 6, 9] 
valid_indexes = magic_function(arr.A, values)
```

or in numpy:

```
arr = np.ndarray(...)
values = [3, 6, 9] 
valid_indexes = magic_function(arr[13, :], values)
```

In other words I'm looking for element-wise `in` operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)

```
arr.loc[arr.A.isin([3,6,9])]
```

Answer (score 4):

From NumPy you could use the `numpy.in1d` function:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([5, 10, 13, 7, 2, 2, 4, 18, 9, 3, 1], dtype=np.int32)
values = np.array([10, 2, 9])
valid_indexes = np.in1d(arr, values)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html